# if no route added form action is is not created why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I Have this in a  view in an area

```
<form action='@Url.Action("/DeleteCoverage")'></form>
```

but this gives only the following html

```
<form action=''></form>
```

but the following code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteCoverage", "Coverage", new { area = "Coverage" },      FormMethod.Post, new { id = "delform" }))
```

gives html

```
 <form action="/Coverage/DeleteCoverage/af361feb-1818-430b-803c-e332a162b0e2" id="delform" method="post">
```

I get this HTML only if i add a route for this method. Other wise it just becomes `action=""`

Why i am not getting proper HTML if I don't add route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly using the `Url.Action` helper. This helper has [several overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx) and expects you to pass action, controller, route values, ... Currently you are passing `/DeleteCoverage` which is invalid action name (action names cannot start with `/`).

So pick one of the overloads and use it correctly:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("DeleteCoverage", "Coverage", new { area = "Coverage" })"></form>
```

Oh and by the way you should probably use `Html.BeginForm` to generate your form tags instead of hardcoding them.